# Eagle PCB Polygon GND width

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, polygon

I am trying to convert 24V to 3.3V for my PCB design. 2 loads using 24V 3A, so I am using 60 Width (53.8 enough in this [trace-width-calculator](https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html) ). I am using GND polygon for 2 layer (My PCB has 2 layer). I realize polygon plane GND's width is 12. I guess this is not enough for my 24V 3A GND trace.

So should I do my wider GND traces by myself?

Or is there a way to do it?

Is there such a thing as the ability to cover all the pads?

Or is it just okay ?

Thank you.
(This one is my first PCB (with SMD components), I am trying to finish it like almost 8 months. It has only MCU and ethernet module. I was almost about to send it to the manufacturer, I had this idea and I came here for ask. Probably this is easy question and I am sorry for this.)

[image][image]

Comment: @DaveTweed Would you be willing to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine. Each pad with thermal relief has four separate connections to the polygon, which adds up to more than enough. If you're planning to hand-solder this, you really do not want to eliminate the thermal relief.

Comment: thank you. I will stick to the polygon then. I shared polygon properties, I changed with size. It was 8mil, I change it to the 12 mil. Is this cause anything ?

Comment: The "width" of a polygon is also the width of the stroke used to "paint" the interior of the polygon. Using a larger width will reduce the size of the resulting Gerber file (fewer strokes required), but it will also reduce the ability for the algorithm to connect through the gaps between closely-spaced pins. If this results in long "slots" in your ground plane, you might consider reducing the width.